# Swift/SpriteKit: Numerical variable always returning 0

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm new to Swift, and am working in XCode 6.1.1
The game I'm making is a math game- so I'm using ints to spawn equation values and answer values. The answer values will be held by sheep characters, and the sheep are SKNodes.

First- delcare global vars for sheep values. The reason for having a separate var for sheeps and answer is because I will later check to see if the randomly generated int for sheeps is equal to the answer.

```
   var sheepValue = 0
var equation = 0
var answer = 0
```

Then, in the spawn sheep method, I also generate a unique int value for every sheep spawned- and have the sheep print that value out on itself.

```
 let sheepValue = generateNumber3()
    let myString = String(sheepValue)
    let sheepLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "MERKIN")
    sheepLabel.name = "sheepmathproblem"
    sheepLabel.fontColor = SKColor.darkGrayColor()
    sheepLabel.fontSize = 30
    sheepLabel.text = myString
    sheep.addChild(sheepLabel)
```

Here's the random number generator method:

```
   func generateNumber3() -> UInt32 {

    //generate random number from 1-10
    return arc4random_uniform(20) + 1

}
```

And here's where I print the sheepValue in console. For some reason, the sheepValue and equation values never change from when I declared them as global variables. I thought by using "let sheepValue = generateNumber3()" would change the global variable's value, but I'm obviously missing something.

```
if CGRectIntersectsRect(sheep.frame, self.sandman.frame) {
    if self.sheepValue == self.equation {
        println("sheepValue: \(self.sheepValue)")
        println("equation: \(self.equation)")
        hitSheep.append(sheep)

        }

    }
```

Thanks for you help! Sorry if this seems basic, I'm not sure why this isn't working.. I did try declaring the vars within methods, but I need to check sheep value in other methods beside the spawnSheep method, so I thought the global var was good enough so I can access it in other methods..or somehow making the int a property of sheep- which I'm not sure how to do either or if it would be a good idea. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let sheepValue = generateNumber3()
```

is in the local scope of your spawn method. This is not the same as the sheepValue variable defined in the class as

```
var sheepValue = 0
```

If you want it the same, do the this:

```
self.sheepValue = generateNumber3()
```

Comment: Ok, so I changed let sheepValue = generateNumber3( ) to self.sheepValue = generateNumber3( ) and I'm getting an error that says 'UInt32' is not convertible to 'Int'- this change was only made in the spawnSheep method. But I'm guessing because I declared var sheepValue outside of the class, the 'self' points to that var within gameScene?

Comment: This is because you are implicitly defining the var sheepValue, which makes it an Int. You'll need to either be explicit or type cast. Explicit would be `var sheepValue:UInt32` (to match `generateNumber3`) or `self.sheepValue = Int(generateNumber3())`

Comment: Thanks! I got it, tinkered with it a bit, and realized another issue. Having the sheepValue as a global means that this value will always change when a new sheep appears, meaning the existing sheep on screen will no longer hold a value. I was trying to have each sheep hold their own unique value upon spawn and hold it while they're on screen. I'm trying to get sheepValue to be declared within the spawnSheep method. But having trouble comparing the private sheepValue in my checkCollision method (if sheep.sheepValue == self.equation) sheep.sheepValue=Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(12))+1)

Comment: Thanks! I got it, tinkered with it a bit, and realized another issue. Having the sheepValue as a global means that this value will always change when a new sheep appears, meaning the existing sheep on screen will no longer hold a value. I was trying to have each sheep hold their own unique value upon spawn and hold it while they're on screen. I'm trying to get sheepValue to be declared within the spawnSheep method. But having trouble comparing the private sheepValue in my checkCollision method (if sheep.sheepValue == self.equation)

Comment: To clarify, I have: sheep.sheepValue=Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(12))+1) and am getting the error. I'm trying to get sheepValue to be a member of sheep, so I can call it in other methods as sheep.sheepValue. Sorry for this lengthy comment, but you've been helpful in pointing me in the right direction! :D